# Executing dynamic list of Actions with parameters

Tags: c#, action

I'm building a list of Actions based on some other data. Each action should do a call to a method, and the list of actions should be performed in parallel. I have the following code that works just fine for parameterless methods:

```
private void Execute() {

    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        actions.Add(new Action(DoSomething));
    }

    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
}

private void DoSomething() {
    Console.WriteLine("Did something");
}
```

But how can I do something similar where the methods have parameters? The following does not work:

```
private void Execute() {
    List<Action<int>> actions = new List<Action<int>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        actions.Add(new Action(DoSomething(i))); // This fails because I can't input the value to the action like this
    }

    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray()); // This also fails because Invoke() expects Action[], not Action<T>[]
}

private void DoSomething(int value) {
    Console.WriteLine("Did something #" + value);
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to use it in a lambda, because the syntax you're using evaluates the function.  i.e.  `new Action(i => DoSomething(i))`. EDIT:  Actually that's not it, but I think you need to do something similar to bake your value into the function call.

Comment: And you're still going to use a `List<Action>`, because you still want a parameterless delegate, yes?

Comment: You don't want `Action<int>` because you're not passing a parameter to the action _when it's invoked_.  You're providing the parameter value as part of the delegate definition. If you just leave it as `Action` then both problems are solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just keep your `actions` variable as a `List<Action>` instead of a `List<Action<int>>` and both problems are solved:

```
private void Execute() {
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        actions.Add(new Action(() => DoSomething(i)));         }

    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray()); 
}

private void DoSomething(int value) {
    Console.WriteLine("Did something #" + value);
}
```

The reason you want `Action` is becuase you're not passing the parameter *when the action is invoked* - you're providing the parameter value *as part of the delegate definition* (note that the delegate parameter is changed to a lambda with no input parameters - `() => DoSomething(i)`), so it's an `Action`, not an `Action<int>`.

Comment: Important part to note is `new Action(() => DoSomething(i))` rather than `new Action(DoSomething(i))`.  You want the lambda in there, rather than just dumping the method call in there.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pitfall that I ran into when using an indexed forloop with the creation of threads.

When giving the Parameter `i` directly into the `DoSomething` method the Output is:

> Did something #5
>
> Did something #5
>
> Did something #5
>
> Did something #5
>
> Did something #5

It is probably not what one wants when using a Loop and changing the counting variable. But if you save it temporarily into a new variable like:

```
class Program
{

    private static void Execute()
    {
        List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // save it temporarily and pass the temp_var variable
            int tmp_var = i;
            actions.Add(new Action(() => DoSomething(tmp_var)));
        }

        Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
    }

    private static void DoSomething(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did something #" + value);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Execute();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

you actually get the counting variable in its full Beauty:

> Did something #0
>
> Did something #2
>
> Did something #3
>
> Did something #1
>
> Did something #4

apparently in C# the variable survives the Loop (I don't know where) and when the thread is executed the Compiler will jump to the line

```
actions.Add(new Action(() => DoSomething(i)));
```

and take the value of `i` which it had when the Loop ended! If you would use `i` to index a `List` or `array` it would always lead to an `OutOfBoundsException` !
This drove me mad for a week until I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

As j.i.h. pointed out, you need to use it in a Lamba. Change your snippet to this:

```
private void Execute()
{
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        actions.Add(() => DoSomething(i));
    }

    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
}

private void DoSomething(int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Did something #" + value);
}
```

You can omit `new Action(() => DoSomething(i));` and directly pass the Lamba to `List.Add` like this `List.Add(() => DoSomething(i));`

Answer (score 0):

it seems like what you actually want is just:

```
private void Execute() {
    Parallel.For(0, 5, DoSomething);
}

private void DoSomething(int value) {
    Console.WriteLine("Did something #" + value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mong Jhu answer is perfect, I wanted to show how `Action<int>` can be used for same output.

```
private static void Execute1()
        {
            List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                actions.Add(new Action(() => DoSomething(i)));
            }
            Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
        }
        private static void Execute()
        {
            List<Action<int>> actions = new List<Action<int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                actions.Add(new Action<int>((x) => DoSomething(i)));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < actions.Count; i++)
            {
                Parallel.Invoke(() => { actions[0](0); });
            }
        }
```