# Pass variable to action as value

Tags: c#

So I need to build dynamically  a set of `Action`s with a foreach, something like this:

```
Action<object[]> actions;
int index = -1;
foreach(var item in itemCollection)
{
    actionsParametersArray[++index] = aParameter;
    actions += x => Console.WriteLine(index);
    actions += x => DoAction((int)actionsParametersArray[index]);
    actionsParametersArray[++index] = otherParameter;
    actions += x => DoOtherAction((MyCustomClass)actionsParametersArray[index]);
}
```

The problem is that when the actions get called they ALL use the last `index` value, f.i. if there are 10 items in `itemCollection`, all actions will try to take `actionsParametersArray[19]` as their parameter.

I thought that I read somewhere that types as `int` are always passed by value, but it seems that the value are be passed as reference so the last value of `index` is the only one that are working in all cases. So I supposed that was the error. Therefore, I thought that if I defined a new variable inside the block it will pass the variable to "value":

```
int parIndex = -1;
foreach(var item in itemCollection)
{
    int index;
    actionsParametersArray[++parIndex] = aParameter;
    index = parIndex;
    actions += x => DoAction((int)actionsParametersArray[index]);
    actionsParametersArray[++parIndex] = otherParameter;
    index = parIndex;
    actions += x => DoOtherAction((MyCustomClass)actionsParametersArray[index]);
}
```

It doesn't work either, it's the same but it just take the last value of one iteration (in this case, the parameter indexes would be 1, 3, 5...).

It only works if I create a new variable for each new `Action` (I've also read [this question which gives the same answer, specifically Mong Zhu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882931/executing-dynamic-list-of-actions-with-parameters)), which is not the ideal solution, honestly, since I have several iterations and actions per iteration... I'd need a lot of variables.

Are there any other solution to this?

Comment: You have a captured loop variable, therefore always getting the last value when action is invoked

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It seems that it answer the question... there's no other way but to create a proxy variable each time, or to find another way of create the actions. I'll read that Jon Skeet article about closures referenced in that question anyway.